# Why isn't my stateless widget properly consuming data from the provider?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-provider

My goal is to generate selection chips(**SelectionItems**) in a **Wrap** widget which lives inside it's parent widget (**SelectionRow**). The list of data(**rowBody**) to be used to generate the chips is being passed down to the parent widget, then later transformed into models which I now intend to use to pass down to a function to generate the widgets as seen in the code below.

```
class SelectionRow extends StatelessWidget {

  SelectionRow({this.rowCategoryHeader, this.rowBody});
  final String rowCategoryHeader;
  final List rowBody;

  //SelectionOptionModelData selection= SelectionOptionModelData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Generate the models from the list acquired from the database
    Provider.of<SelectionOptionModelData>(context).generateModelsFromList(rowBody);

    //TODO: selectionOptionModels doesn't get any content in the array returned to it.

    return Consumer<SelectionOptionModelData>(
      builder: (context, selectionOptionModels, child) {

        print(selectionOptionModels.getSelectionOptionModels);

        return Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    rowCategoryHeader.toUpperCase(),
                    style: kROW_HEADING_TEXT,
                  ),
                ),
                Wrap(
                  spacing: 5,
                  runSpacing: 5,
                  children:
                      //Generate widgets from the selectionOptionModels in the provider.
                      generateSelectionItemWidgets(
                       selectionOptionModels.getSelectionOptionModels,
                          context
                      ),
                )
                        ...
```

I now went ahead and created a provider class which houses the function to take the list of data (**rowBody**) along with other functions as seen in the code below. This is the provider that is being consumed by my **SelectionRow** Widget above.

```
class SelectionOptionModelData with ChangeNotifier{


  List<SelectionModel> _selectionOptionModels = [];

  void generateModelsFromList(List<Map<String,dynamic>> ingredientList) {

    for (var ingredient in ingredientList) {
      _selectionOptionModels.add(
          SelectionModel(
              name: ingredient['title'],
              price: ingredient['price']
          )
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }


   List<SelectionModel> get getSelectionOptionModels{
     return _selectionOptionModels;
  }


  void updateSelectionOptionModel(SelectionModel selectionOption){
    selectionOption.toggleSelected();
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

My problem now is that, the **generateSelectionItemWidget** function in my **Wrap** widget inside the parent **SelectionRow** somehow doesn't receive the models it needs to generate those widget. So I really can't seem to figure out why it's like that seeing as how the the function was supposed to have received the required models from the consumed provider.

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDITED**

Below is the main file where I wrapped the tree with all my providers.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<SelectionOptionModelData>(create: (_)=>SelectionOptionModelData(),),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ComboList>(create: (_)=>ComboList()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ComboPrice>(create: (_)=>ComboPrice())
      ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
            ),
            home: CustomizeScreen(),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

ERROR ENCOUNTERED AFTER GETTING IT TO WORK

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for SelectionOptionModelData:
flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
flutter: This _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<SelectionOptionModelData> widget cannot be marked as needing to
flutter: build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked
flutter: as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.
flutter: This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
flutter: dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during
flutter: this build phase.
flutter: The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
flutter:   _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<SelectionOptionModelData>
flutter: The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
flutter:   SelectionRow
flutter:
```

Comment: I don't see any reference of Provider in your code. You should share more code if you want some help

Comment: Alright let me share where I wrapped the tree with the provider class.

Comment: I never use the ChangeNotifierProvider but I think there is a problem with `SelectionOptionModelData().generateModelsFromList(rowBody);`. You'll probably have to get your `SelectionOptionModelData` using `Provider.of<SelectionOptionModelData>(context).generateModelsFromList(rowBody);`. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Let me give that a try and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked but, it threw me an error. Let me share that for you to see

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that you get `Provider.of<SelectionOptionModelData>(context).generateModelsFromList(rowBody);`inside the build method of `SelectionRow`. I think you can add the `listen: false` attribute : `Provider.of<SelectionOptionModelData>(context, listen: false).generateModelsFromList(rowBody);`. or maybe you can call your method in the initState() method

Comment: What is this? Java? C#? Add the appropriate tag, please

Comment: setting listen to false didn't do the trick. I could call it in the initState but that would mean changing it into a stateful widget which i'm afraid might be an overkill.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for noticing, let me include dart in there.

Comment: I think there is a design concerns regarding the error but I can't test for you sry. Try to understand why it says `This _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<SelectionOptionModelData> widget cannot be marked as needing to
flutter: build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.`

Comment: Alright man, i'll do that. Thanks again for the help.